# Add svg icon into button with css/html?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have the icon displayed inside the button tag, see code below:

```css
#header-search {
  width: 200px;
  background: @header-color;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 0px solid;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: -50%;
}

#header-search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

#search-button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: -50%;
}

.header-view-logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-icon {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="search-button" />
<svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

But the icon is just displayed all over the place really big one, how can i get it to fit inside the button ?

Comment: From what I can see, the problem lies in the fact that your button tag is being closed before the svg even begins.

Comment: Personally I'd use it as a data-uri, background-image. Inline just ... looks weird?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Not sure if the button is not closed or just you copied it here and forgot to close it.

```css
#search-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
    
#search-button svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button id="search-button">
    <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
 </button>
```

Comment: the svg will inherit the width of its parent (behavior observed in Google Chrome). should be no need to specify it's width and height in addition to the parent height. set the parent width and height to whatever you want the svg's width and height to be. in Chrome, width and height at svg level are being completely ignored.

Comment: You also need to remove the slash in the opening button tag.  It's currently self-closing.

`<button id="search-button">`

Answer (score 11):

I've modified your code a bit:

```css
#header-search {
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12pt;
  border: 0px solid;
  outline: 0;
  vertical-align: -50%;
}

.header-view-logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-icon {
  fill: black;
}

#search-button {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
  <button id="search-button">
    <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
        <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

The two problems were:

1. You didn't close your `button` properly, it needs to end **after** the SVG
2. You needed to specify a width for the button (As you can see I left off some of your other CSS)

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you, doing it this way:

```css
#header-search, #search-button {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    height: 1.7rem;
    padding: 0;
}

#header-search {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0.8rem 0.7rem
}

#search-button {
    width: 2.4rem;
    height: 1.9rem;
}

#search-icon {
  width: 1.3rem;
  height: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <input id="header-search" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button id="search-button">
        <svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have checked your code,Plz try to do this.

box-model(Depending on height,weight,margin,padding) only reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

  #header-search {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
}

#header-search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
}

#search-button {
    background-color: red !important;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding: 0;
    width: 40px;
}
.header-view-logo {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-icon {
    fill:white;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
<input type="search" id="header-search" placeholder="Search..." />
<button id="search-button">
<svg id="search-icon" class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z">
<path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z">
</svg>
</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**

> this answer dont solve your problem, it's other way to add icon.svg to
> button

**

you can use embed include button tag:

```
<button><embed src="icon.svg" /></button>
```

Answer (score -8):

```
<svg height="20" width="40" >
<path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5  3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"/>
```

Comment: Please review some of the other answers to see what constitutes a good answer. EG explanations of what the code does to solve the problem.